# PackageName in DevicePolicyManager.clearPackagePersistentPreferredActivities(ComponentName admin,String packageName)

Tags: android, device-policy-manager

What does represent the `packageName` in `DevicePolicyManager.clearPackagePersistentPreferredActivities(ComponentName admin,String packageName)`? Is it the package name of the admin or is it the package name in of the activity of `addPersistentPreferredActivity(ComponentName, IntentFilter, ComponentName)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From official docs addressed here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#clearPackagePersistentPreferredActivities(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String)

> Called by a profile owner or device owner to remove all persistent
>   intent handler preferences associated with the given package that were
>   set by addPersistentPreferredActivity(ComponentName, IntentFilter,
>   ComponentName).

So it is the later one from your question.